# Plotting Using Seaborn tsplot with Different Time Series

Tags: python, time, seaborn

I'm trying to visualize a Gillespie algorithm with tsplot, however the points aren't connected since the set of time points are different for each replicate and treatment. Is there anyway to fix this? Here's code with the gammas example where I changed a time point:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(22)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")
print(gammas)
print(gammas.iloc[3000,0])
print(gammas.iloc[3060,0])
gammas.iloc[3000,0]=5.050505050515
ax = sns.tsplot(time="timepoint", value="BOLD signal",unit="subject", condition="ROI",data=gammas,err_style='unit_traces')
```

Answer (score 2):

The gap is happening because you end up with `nans` in your data when there are "missing" observations at some timepoints. Try:

```
sns.tsplot(..., estimator=np.nanmean)
```

which for me with your example gives a solid line.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be a start. However this only connects the mean, and not to the 'right' point. But thanks for explaining the problem, I understand it better now.

Comment: You will likely find it quite easy to accomplish what you are trying to do with the lower level pandas or matplotlib functions.